# I/O errors backing up to an SMB Share from MSSQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014, aws

I'm having some issues with SQL backups which are being written to an SMB share on a AWS Storage Gateway Appliance from an EC2 SQL Server. I'm consistently getting the same error in the SQL Event log for two SQL instances saying:

> BackupIoRequest::ReportIoError: Write failure on backup device
>   'Path_To_Backup' Operating System Error 59 (An unexpected network
>   error occurred)

This causes several DB backups to fail at exactly the same time to the second, resulting in an invalid backup file. This happens 2 hours into the backup of this 150-200GB database at around 1AM. The weird part is I have other servers backing up to this path which do not experience the failure. I've been working with AWS Support and they've been unable to find a related network or Storage Gateway Error. I have scoured the Windows/SQL Logs but can't find any correlated events. What errors I do have seem to be dead ends for my particular error.

Is there anything I can monitor in SQL server to collect more information about the backup failure than I'm getting from the default Windows/SQL Logs? Is it a valid backup strategy to backup to a share when you're writing ~600gb a night from many SQL instances?

Comment: This still seems like something you should continue working with AWS Support. I don't think your peers are going to be able to help you solve a 3rd party's intermittent network issues. Yes, there are [additional backup diagnostics you can capture](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/t-sql-tuesday-66-babysitting-a-slow-backup-or-restore/), but if the network fails, the network fails, and the backup process is not going to gain magic insight into the network. Personally, I would back up locally (faster), copy to the share (safer), then delete the local once the copy has been verified.

Comment: Any suggestions on tools to perform that copy/verify when going from local storage to the share? I considered using RoboCopy or PowerShell copy-item but I was a little concerned about how to verify everything is successfully making it to the share. I still have my open ticket with AWS and they've been really helpful, I was just hoping to get more information around the failure from SQL.

Comment: You verify by trying to restore the backup. Anything less is not verifying anything.

Comment: Good point. I agree with you there, a project I've been pushing for is a separate SQL server to test restores on and a process to validate the data is all there.

Comment: Have you tried to run the backup at a different time? Could it be a contention issue since your network bandwidth may be the limiting factor?

Comment: Based on what I can see in cloudwatch and what AWS Support tells me we're not exceeding the network or EBS bandwidth of the SQL server or the Storage Gateway. I can confirm if I run these backups on their own they complete without errors. I only have issues during the scheduled backup window where we're kicking off quite a few backups at the same time. The odd part is when the error occurs most of the traffic has dropped off and only a few of the large dbs are still in the process of backing up.

Answer (score 2):

Just following up on this. Backups have been running flawlessly since we made a change to the SMB timeout in the registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\LanmanWorkstation\\Parameters]  
"SessTimeout"=dword:00000258
```

What that works out to is 600 seconds or a 10 minute timeout for SMB sessions from the SQL Server, the default is 60 seconds. it needs to be saved in hex.

I found it in the article: [CIFS and SMB Timeouts in Windows](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/openspecification/2013/03/19/cifs-and-smb-timeouts-in-windows/)

It's the line with a heading of Client Session timeout.

We arrived at this solution after verifying in a packet capture that the session was being ended by the SQL Server sending an RST, ACK to end the session.

Comment: You might want to consider merging your accounts. Have a look at: [How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or OpenID / registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous) for more details.